# HtmlUnit: select specific text, generated by JavaScript

Tags: html, htmlunit

I am using the HtmlUnit to get the text from a web page what is probably generated by Javascript
 (since it is not in the HTML code and links).
The Url i  look is [stepstone](https://www.stepstone.de/stellenangebote--Projektleiter-m-w-Forschung-Entwicklung-Automotive-Security-Standardisierung-und-prototypische-Implementierung-Eching-bei-Muenchen-DENSO-AUTOMOTIVE-Deutschland-GmbH--4675635-inline.html)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class HtmlUnit2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
                "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(Level.OFF);
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

        String uri = "https://www.stepstone.de/stellenangebote--Projektleiter-m-w-Forschung-Entwicklung-Automotive-Security-Standardisierung-und-prototypische-Implementierung-Eching-bei-Muenchen-DENSO-AUTOMOTIVE-Deutschland-GmbH--4675635-inline.html";
        HtmlPage page;
        try {
            final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52); // Imitating a specific browser
            page = webClient.getPage(uri);

            final String pageAsText = page.asText();
            System.out.println(pageAsText);

        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {

            // e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Somehow I can not get the text from page.asXml() and only as page.asText(), howewer the output contains lots of garbage and useless words from other tags:

```
    Projektleiter (m/w) Forschung & Entwicklung – Automotive Security Standardisierung und prototypische Implementierung - Job bei DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH in Eching bei München


Unsere Webseite verwendet Cookies, um Ihnen eine bessere Nutzererfahrung zu ermöglichen. Durch die Nutzung unserer Webseite stimmen Sie unserer Verwendung von Cookies zu. Mehr











Stellenanzeige aufgeben


Für Arbeitgeber




Login





Lebenslauf anlegen


DE
















Suchen


Erweiterte Suche











DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH

Projektleiter (m/w) Forschung & Entwicklung – Automotive Security Standardisierung und prototypische Implementierung

Eching bei München
 Feste Anstellung
 Vollzeit
 Erschienen: vor einem Monat




Jetzt bewerben

 Merken








DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH DENSO zählt als globaler Automobil­zulieferer für Erst­ausrüstung und Aftermarket mit rund 151.000 Mitarbeitern in 38 Ländern weltweit zu den führenden Entwicklern und Anbietern von Komponenten und Systemen in den Bereichen Klimatisierung, Antriebs­strang, Elektrik, Elektronik, Fahrer­assistenz und Infotainment. Zur Verstärkung unserer Abteilung Corporate Research & Development in Eching bei München suchen wir ab sofort einen Projektleiter (m/w) Forschung & Entwicklung – Automotive Security Standardisierung und prototypische Implementierung Wir suchen einen kompetenten Projektleiter (m/w) in Eching bei München. Die stetig wachsende Vernetzung von Fahrzeugen führt zu einem deutlich gesteigerten Angriffspotenzial. Innerhalb des Fahrzeugs wandeln sich die statisch konfigurierten Systeme in Systeme mit dynamischen Zuweisungen und Abläufen. Sie werden in dieser Stelle für die Planung sowie Durchführung von Forschungs- und Entwick­lungsaufgaben für den Bereich Automotive Security verantwortlich sein. Diese werden Sie in enger Zusammenarbeit mit anderen Entwicklungsabteilungen innerhalb Europas sowie weltweit durchführen. Hauptaugenmerk liegt in der Ver­wertung der Erkenntnisse und Ergebnisse der nationalen, europäischen als auch internationalen Standardisierung sowie dem Transfer zur Unterstützung von Kundenprojekten. Im Detail werden Sie bei der internationalen Standardisierung aktiv mitarbeiten und dabei DENSOs technische Interessen vertreten, die nationale Standardisierung unterstützen und dazu engen Dialog mit den Gremienpartnern über ent­stehende Normen führen, die F&E-Prototypprojekte im Bereich Automotive Security sowie die Planung als auch Durch­füh­rung daran ausgerichteter Unterprojekte unterstützen und sich selber weiterentwickeln, um ein führender technischer Experte (m/w) in DENSOs Wachstumsbereichen zu werden. Erforderliche Qualifikation: Universitätsabschluss (Diplom, Master oder Promotion) im Bereich Informatik, Elektrotechnik oder andere verwandte Ingenieurstudiengänge mit Bezug zur Automobiltechnik Solides Wissen in IT Security, wie kryptographischen Verfahren, Risikoanalysen und -bewertungen, idealerweise in der Anwendung auf den Automobilsektor Sicherer und effizienter Umgang mit IT und Erfahrungen mit Linux-Entwicklungen, idealerweise Embedded Linux Erfahrungen mit Web-Entwicklung und Server-Verwaltung Erste Erfahrungen im Bereich Erfindungen und Patentschutz Herausragende Kommunikations- und Präsentationsfähigkeiten Verhandlungssichere und überzeugende Persönlichkeit Teamfähigkeit mit interkulturellen Kompetenzen bei gleichzeitiger Fähigkeit, selbstständig und gut organisiert zu arbeiten Bereitschaft, über die Grenzen von akademischer Forschung hinauszudenken Führerschein der Klasse B und die Bereitschaft zu gelegentlichen nationalen als auch internationalen Dienst­reisen Verhandlungssichere Deutsch- und Englischkenntnisse in Wort und Schrift (Geschäftssprache ist Englisch) Bitte senden Sie uns Ihre Bewerbung mit Angabe Ihrer Verfügbarkeit, Ihrer Gehaltsvorstellung und der Stellennummer 201709 in Deutsch und Englisch direkt an jobs@denso-auto.de. DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH HR Specialist Frau Bianca Petritsch Tel: 08165/944-232, jobs@denso-auto.de www.denso-europe.com www.denso-local.com/deutschland Follow us on twitter



Jetzt bewerben




Unternehmen




11 Stellen


DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH

Fahrzeugbau/-zulieferer




Standort

 Karte anzeigen


DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH
 Eching, Deutschland







Weitere Jobs

1.
Nach Berufsfeld

2. Ingenieure und technisc...
3. Einkauf, Materialwirtsc...
4. IT


1.
Nach Standort

2. Eching
3. München
4. Bayern
5. Ostbayern
6. Südbayern


1.
Nach Jobtitel

2. Applikationsingenieur/i...
3. Entwicklungsingenieur/i...
4. Head of Display











Über StepStone

Wer wir sind
Presse
Partner werden


Karriere bei StepStone
StepStone Blog



Feedback

Geben Sie uns Feedback


Apps





















Datenschutzerklärung
 Nutzungsbedingungen
 Kontakt
 Informationen über Ihre Rechte
 AGB
 Impressum


Copyright © StepStone GmbH 1996 - 2017
```

And i want to have only this element:

```
DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH DENSO zählt als globaler Automobil­zulieferer für Erst­ausrüstung und Aftermarket mit rund 151.000 Mitarbeitern in 38 Ländern weltweit zu den führenden Entwicklern und Anbietern von Komponenten und Systemen in den Bereichen Klimatisierung, Antriebs­strang, Elektrik, Elektronik, Fahrer­assistenz und Infotainment. Zur Verstärkung unserer Abteilung Corporate Research & Development in Eching bei München suchen wir ab sofort einen Projektleiter (m/w) Forschung & Entwicklung – Automotive Security Standardisierung und prototypische Implementierung Wir suchen einen kompetenten Projektleiter (m/w) in Eching bei München. Die stetig wachsende Vernetzung von Fahrzeugen führt zu einem deutlich gesteigerten Angriffspotenzial. Innerhalb des Fahrzeugs wandeln sich die statisch konfigurierten Systeme in Systeme mit dynamischen Zuweisungen und Abläufen. Sie werden in dieser Stelle für die Planung sowie Durchführung von Forschungs- und Entwick­lungsaufgaben für den Bereich Automotive Security verantwortlich sein. Diese werden Sie in enger Zusammenarbeit mit anderen Entwicklungsabteilungen innerhalb Europas sowie weltweit durchführen. Hauptaugenmerk liegt in der Ver­wertung der Erkenntnisse und Ergebnisse der nationalen, europäischen als auch internationalen Standardisierung sowie dem Transfer zur Unterstützung von Kundenprojekten. Im Detail werden Sie bei der internationalen Standardisierung aktiv mitarbeiten und dabei DENSOs technische Interessen vertreten, die nationale Standardisierung unterstützen und dazu engen Dialog mit den Gremienpartnern über ent­stehende Normen führen, die F&E-Prototypprojekte im Bereich Automotive Security sowie die Planung als auch Durch­füh­rung daran ausgerichteter Unterprojekte unterstützen und sich selber weiterentwickeln, um ein führender technischer Experte (m/w) in DENSOs Wachstumsbereichen zu werden. Erforderliche Qualifikation: Universitätsabschluss (Diplom, Master oder Promotion) im Bereich Informatik, Elektrotechnik oder andere verwandte Ingenieurstudiengänge mit Bezug zur Automobiltechnik Solides Wissen in IT Security, wie kryptographischen Verfahren, Risikoanalysen und -bewertungen, idealerweise in der Anwendung auf den Automobilsektor Sicherer und effizienter Umgang mit IT und Erfahrungen mit Linux-Entwicklungen, idealerweise Embedded Linux Erfahrungen mit Web-Entwicklung und Server-Verwaltung Erste Erfahrungen im Bereich Erfindungen und Patentschutz Herausragende Kommunikations- und Präsentationsfähigkeiten Verhandlungssichere und überzeugende Persönlichkeit Teamfähigkeit mit interkulturellen Kompetenzen bei gleichzeitiger Fähigkeit, selbstständig und gut organisiert zu arbeiten Bereitschaft, über die Grenzen von akademischer Forschung hinauszudenken Führerschein der Klasse B und die Bereitschaft zu gelegentlichen nationalen als auch internationalen Dienst­reisen Verhandlungssichere Deutsch- und Englischkenntnisse in Wort und Schrift (Geschäftssprache ist Englisch) Bitte senden Sie uns Ihre Bewerbung mit Angabe Ihrer Verfügbarkeit, Ihrer Gehaltsvorstellung und der Stellennummer 201709 in Deutsch und Englisch direkt an jobs@denso-auto.de. DENSO AUTOMOTIVE Deutschland GmbH HR Specialist Frau Bianca Petritsch Tel: 08165/944-232, jobs@denso-auto.de www.denso-europe.com www.denso-local.com/deutschland Follow us on twitter
```

How to focus on this text since is generated by javascript and does not present in xml/dom model?

Answer (score 0):

Because the additional content is retreived via ajax and ajax is async, you have to wait a bit.

This works here with the latest SNAPSHOT

```
    String url = "https://www.stepstone.de/stellenangebote--Projektleiter-m-w-Forschung-Entwicklung-Automotive-Security-Standardisierung-und-prototypische-Implementierung-Eching-bei-Muenchen-DENSO-AUTOMOTIVE-Deutschland-GmbH--4675635-inline.html";

    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_52)) {
        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);

        System.out.println("----------------");
        System.out.println(page.asText());
        System.out.println("----------------");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but i dont want to  use asText(), will the result of JS  be in xml there, so i can focus on the text ( it is in the table, generated by JS).
Second, i want to process a lot of data from the same page. Means
is will be the same JS for each page like that. 
Is it possible not to wait or not retrieve the scripts each time but store it locally somehow? That would speedup it.

Comment: asText only converts the current dom tree into text; as XML does the same but with xml as output. So the answer is yes, wait just waits until the ajax request is done. Then you have the (now complete) dom treee and you can use the usual api to address every element you like. Give it a try

Comment: Sorry but i do not understand your second question.

Comment: I am processing a big amount of the <b>same</b> links from the same page.
As you may guess, there will be same scripts for each link. I guess the HtmlUnit will wait until script is downloaded each time, since its builded like that and the idea was to store scripts locally somehow

Comment: As far as i remeber scripts are cached like the browsers do. You can try that; use a WebProxy like Charles to see the traffic on the wire. If you think there is something wrong and/or we can improve something please open an issue.